# using Pentaho Data Integration how to connect database via MariaDB

Tags: pentaho, mariadb, kettle

when i try to connect i am getting below errors :

`Error connecting to database [cha]` `org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:`
`Error occured while trying to connect to the database`

`Error connecting to database: (using class org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver)`
`Could not connect to 20.0.1.93:3306 : Connection refused`

org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

`Error connecting to database: (using class org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver)`
`Could not connect to 20.0.1.93:3306 : Connection refused`

```
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:366)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:315)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:277)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:267)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:86)
at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2464)
at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:533)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:329)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:139)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:123)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton.access$500(SwtButton.java:26)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton$4.widgetSelected(SwtButton.java:119)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtDialog.show(SwtDialog.java:378)
at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtDialog.show(SwtDialog.java:304)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:115)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:62)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.step.BaseStepDialog$3.widgetSelected(BaseStepDialog.java:628)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInputDialog.open(TableInputDialog.java:395)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonStepsDelegate.editStep(SpoonStepsDelegate.java:136)
at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.editStep(Spoon.java:7835)....
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem Pentaho related. 
Is the mariaDB User you are using, configured to allow login from the server/workstation you are running Pentaho on?
Is the firewall on the server you are running MariaDB on, configured to allow connections from the server/workstation Pentaho is running on?

You should be able to find enough information about the above and other related information to allow remote access to your MariaDB on this page: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/